# Solving a PDE such as $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(a+1,x)=f(a,x)+x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(a,x)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, problem-solving, functional-equations, delay-differential-equations

I am tying to understand what methods are available to find the analytical form of a function given a system of PDEs which it satisfies. For example, the function $f(a,x)=x^a$ is such that $f(a+1,x)=x^{a+1}=x f(a,x)$. Therefore I would like to understand what methods are available to go from this property:
$$f(a+1,x)=x f(a,x)$$
to this definition:
$$f(a,x)=x^a$$

My understanding is that derivation can lead to differential equations which can sometimes be solved. For example, the above equation for the property leads to:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(a+1,x)=f(a,x)+x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(a,x)$$

One difficulty I have is figuring out how to use this to find the analytical form of f (and since I am not advanced in Calculus I use Mathematica to help when necessary). Another difficulty I am encountering is related to the number of equations which are needed in this case; I do not expect the above property to necessarily yield a unique solution, but how many such properties are required to get at least one solution such as the one I started from? Also, I could just as easily add conditions by taking the partial derivatives for $a$, but I am not sure if this helps... Finally, in my browsing for answers for this, I am wondering if this needs to be considered a "Delay Differential Equation" rather than an ODE (or system of ODEs)...

The problem I am hoping to solve once I understand how to do this simpler version described aboe is actually a bit more general since it relates to the function $f(a,b,x)=x^a(1-x)^b$, which has the similar properties $x f(a,b,x)=f(a+1,b,x)$ and $(1-x) f(a,b,x)=f(a,b+1,x)$. Therefore I am hoping that the answer to this question will enable me to generalize this method to such a situation.

I have asked a [similar question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/278580/trying-to-elicit-a-function-by-defining-pdes-and-using-dsolve-ndsolve) on the Mathematica forum since I am trying to use some of the functions provided by Mathematica to help solve this, and I hope that disclosing this will not be considered cross-posting but rather complementary posting as I am missing two sets of tools to solve this: some mathematical understanding related to how to elicit functions from PDEs, and some Mathematica knowledge as to how it can help me solve the problem once I understand the methodology.

I have also found the following related posts, but solutions seem to be more involved and (perhaps) more problem-specific:

- [Constructing analytic solutions to the delay differential equation $f'(x) = x f(x-1) - f(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3504608/constructing-analytic-solutions-to-the-delay-differential-equation-fx-x-f)
- [Is there a rational function $f(x,a)$ such that $\int_0^1 f(x,a) dx = \frac{\ln(a)}{a}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2852106/is-there-a-rational-function-fx-a-such-that-int-01-fx-a-dx-frac-ln)

Finally, this post relating to the number of conditions will likely help me determine the number of equations needed, though I have trouble understanding which equations actually "add value" to the solve (for example, I doubt that extending to a+2, a+3, ... will help):
[Is there any theorem that tells us how many ICs or BCs are needed for getting the determine solution of a PDE or a set of PDEs?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450367/is-there-any-theorem-that-tells-us-how-many-ics-or-bcs-are-needed-for-getting-th)

*** [EDIT 1] ***

One approach I have tried since posting requires making an assumption regarding the relation between $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(a,x)$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(a+1,x)$. I have tried the following, which is obviously very much informed by the fact that I know the solution:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(a+1,x)=(u+vx)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(a,x)
$$

This reduces the problem to:
$$
f(a,x)=(u+vx-x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(a,x)
$$

I write the following in Mathematica:

```
DSolve[(u + v x) D[f[a, x], x] == f[a, x], f[a, x], {a, x}]
```

And the result is $f[a, x] = (u + v x)^\frac1v C[1][a]$, which is a result I do not understand.

Although doing this exercise was not super helpful, it did get me to notice that I should perhaps bring the following more informative property into the mix:
$$
x^n f(a,x)=f(a+n,x)
$$
(and if it helps for my problem, I am ready to assume that n>0 as well as a>0).

Comment: Have you tried to apply Laplace or Fourrier transform?

Answer (score 3):

Fourier transform will be your best ally to tackle the translation in $a$ without making the differential equation in $x$ more difficult.

Indeed, let's recall that $\mathfrak{F}[f(a+1,x)](t) = f(t,x)e^{it}$. In consequence, your differential equation becomes
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(t,x)e^{it} = f(t,x) + x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(t,x),
$$
which can be rewritten as
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left((e^{it}-x)f(t,a)\right) = 0,
$$
hence
$$
f(t,x) = \frac{C}{e^{it}-x},
$$
where $C$ is constant. Then, the inverse Fourier transform is given by
$$
f(a,x) = \int_\mathbb{R}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{2\pi}\frac{Ce^{ita}}{e^{it}-x}
$$
The (simple) poles of this integrand are located at $t_k = 2\pi ik - i\ln x, k\in\mathbb{Z}$, and their residues are
$$
\mathrm{Res}_{z=t_k}\frac{e^{iza}}{e^{iz}-x} = \lim_{z\rightarrow t_k}\frac{(z-t_k)e^{iza}}{e^{iz}-x} = \lim_{z\rightarrow t_k}\frac{ia(z-t_k)e^{iza} + e^{iza}}{e^{iz}} = e^{it_k(a-1)} = e^{-2\pi k(a-1)}x^{a-1},
$$
thanks to L'Hospital's rule. However, only the residues of singularities with non-negative imaginary part (which depends on $x$ unfortunately) are to be taken into account in the final result, hence
$$
f(a,x) = iCx^{a-1}\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}e^{-2\pi k(a-1)}H\left(k-\frac{\ln x}{2\pi}\right),
$$
where $H$ is the Heaviside function. I'm not sure that there is a "more closed" form nonetheless.

Comment: I realize I am lacking knowledge regarding the Fourier transform, but a simple brush-up via Wikipedia does not seem to be enough for me to understand this answer yet. If you can either detail how you go from one step to the next, or perhaps suggest a good introductory document or website that could help me understand your derivations, I would very much appreciate it. In the meantime, I will work through some tutorials until I can figure out how to either accept your answer or make a more constructive comment.

Comment: @sg1234 Are you more interested in the properties of Fourier/Laplace transforms in relation to differential equations or their concrete computations using complex integration / residues ? Because these topics are dense and can fill a whole semester of complex analysis.

Comment: I am currently speeding through https://www.coursera.org/learn/differential-equations-engineers in order to get to chapter 6 on PDEs and Fourier transforms. Basically, I am trying to understand your solution enough so that I can then generalize, using Mathematica if necessary, my own solutions to $(x^n)(1-x)^m f(a,b,x)=f(a+n,b+m,x)$ to which I would add any necessary equations / conditions to make the solution fit my needs in order to arrive at $x^a(1-x)^b$ for example. So to answer your question, I think I probably need more about the method than actual computations, but I am not sure.

Comment: I have been able to up my game a bit in differential equations. Unfortunately, the class I followed stopped at the use of Fourier series for PDEs. Is there any place I can read up to understand the notation used in your answer? Your very first sttement "let's recall that" is already puzzling to me.

Answer (score 1):

On your first question about how to go from
$$ f(a+1,x) = xf(a,x) $$
to $f(a,x) = x^a$,
it is important to realize that is not implied--I mean there
are many solutions other than $x^a$, as in the answer by Abezhiko.

Take the case $a\ge 0$.
Take any function $f_0(a,x)$ defined for $0\le a\le 1$ and
whatever $x$ you like, the only requirement
(to make $f$ continuous in $a$) being
$$
        f_0(1,x) = xf_0(0,x).
$$
Examples are
$$
 f_0(a,x) = \sin^2(\pi a), \qquad (a-1)g(x)+axg(x) {\rm \ \ any\ function\ } g.
$$
Set
$$
 f(a,x) = f_0(a,x) {\rm\ when\ } 0\le a\le 1.
$$
Then your first equation
defines $f$ recursively for $a>1$:
$$
  f(a,x) = xf(a-1,x) = xf_0(a-1,x) {\rm \ when\ } 1 \le a \le 2,
$$
$$
  f(a,x) = xf(a-1,x) = x^2f_0(a-2,x)  {\rm \ when\ } 2 \le a \le 3,
$$
etc. In a nutshell,
$$
 f(a,x) = x^{[a]}f_0(a-[a],x).
$$
That works because when you add 1 to $a$ the $f_0$ factor doesn't change
but the exponential gives another factor of $x$.

Comment: Thanks! I understand that there are more solutions, and part of my question (though maybe I was not explicit enough in the way I formulated it) is with respect to understanding how to specify a system of equations which helps refine the solution set to desired ones. As for your examples: the periodic solution I get (and that is not one that I desire for my more general case for f(a,b,x)), but I do not understand how $(a−1)g(x)+a x g(x)$ is a solution. More importantly, I fail to understand the method behind eliciting such functions.

Comment: Sorry! that should have been $1-a$, not $a-1$. And for method, it is just that the equation $f(a+1,x)=xf(a,x)$ completely specifies $f$ in any interval $[b,b+1]$ of $a$ if it is known in $[b-1,b]$.